# Wrong output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've to write a program to replace the number multiples of 3 by the word 'ping', multiples of 7 by the word 'pong', and multiples of 3 and 7 by the word 'ping-pong' , this is the code :

```
x = eval(input('Enter a number : '))

for i in range(x,101):
    print(i)
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 :

         print('ping-pong\n')

    if i % 3 == 0:
        print('ping\n')
    elif i % 7 == 0:
        print('pong \n')
```

and this is the output :

```
1
2
3
ping

4
5
6
ping

7
pong 

8
9
ping

10
11
12
ping

13
14
pong 

15
ping
```

where it should be look like this:

```
1
2
ping
4
5
ping
pong
8
ping
10
11
ping
13
pong
ping
```

So how can I replace the number with the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use eval. You are dealing with numbers. Just cast to `int`. Finally, the reason why you are always printing out the number you don't want is because you are always printing before checking any of your conditions. Instead, set an else condition if all your checks fail, and then print the number.

Like this:

```
x = int(input('Enter a number : '))

for i in range(x,101):

    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 :

         print('ping-pong\n')

    if i % 3 == 0:
        print('ping\n')
    elif i % 7 == 0:
        print('pong \n')
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: It's my bad I forgot to mention that I've to take a number form the user cause that I used eval.  It worked now correctly

Answer (score 2):

And the obligatory one-liner,

```
print("\n".join('ping-pong' if not i % 21 else 'pong' if not i % 5 else 'ping' if not i % 3 else str(i) for i in range(int(input('Enter a number: ')), 101)))
```

Comment: and an obligatory +1 for said one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints 'i' no matter what since you have included the `print(i)` statement before the conditional statement. Use an else statement instead. So you code would look like:

```
x = int(input('Enter a number : '))

for i in range(x,101):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 :
         print('ping-pong\n')
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print('ping\n')
    elif i % 7 == 0:
        print('pong \n')
    else:
        print(i)
```

That should work. PS set 101 to 10 for testing purposes. Would be easier.

Comment: I wanted to print all the numbers and replace them with the worlds, so I thought it'd work if i print the loop first. thanks It worked now correctly.

Comment: You're welcome :)! Please mark this as the answer to your question if I've solved your problem :)! @SalehAlswiti

Comment: Perhaps you should cast `x` to `int` before using it in `range`.

Comment: Yep that'd be good, didn't see that. Changed it. @HughBothwell

Comment: @HughBothwell it was about the print (i) statement was in the wrong place

Comment: @M4Shooter I did it :)